# Generalization of the Weierstrass M-test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I had a co-student tell me that if we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty v_n(x)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n$, and if the latter dominates the former *for big enough $n$*, then Weierstrass' M-test applies.

But every single version of the theorem I've ever seen says that it must hold for all $n \ge 1$. So what is true?

If my co-student was in the wrong, and we have a dominating $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n$ that only works for some $n$ strictly bigger than 1, what steps might one take to solve this problem?

Comment: Your co-student is correct. Finitely many terms do not affect the convergence of an infinite series.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend's version is right, moreover, it can be proved from the $n\geq 1$ version (just consider the sums beginning from the $N$-th term where the dominance holds and apply the theorem there, a tail of the series converges so the whole series converges too).